# Char device to access GPS on a Nexus 4 with Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

Trying to access the GPS data on a Nexus 4 phone with Ubuntu Touch on it.
Does anyone know if  there is /dev/ to read the raw NMEA data stream?
I did several researches online but cannot get any info on that.

As far as I understand the gps chip is an Avago device, but I was not able to find the linux drivers (I was hoping to get some low level details reading the driver code)

Answer (score 2):

Best I have found so far is `/usr/bin/test_gps` which gives NMEA output. Other than that you could write a Python script to interface with `dbus` and get the location data. Good examples for GSM modem interface are in `/usr/share/ofono/scripts/`. This will give you a good start.

Comment: I ended up doing this:
#!/bin/bash
test_gps|grep nmea|awk '{print $3}'|grep GP >> /dev/gps

Comment: I have setup a git repo for making a xinetd nmea stream service. https://github.com/cearl/ubuntu-touch-nexus-4